PostGres INSERT ERROR error: invalid message format
I have table like this:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName} (
        id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        value text,
        uploaded boolean DEFAULT false
      )

I get the data from datalogger like this:
"2024-12-20 13:37:23.400",4783.83,5375.243,6897.802,4267.536,4205.374,12072.36,5279.975,7320.997,20.99808,20.53375,-112.3837,-112.5886,-106.6176,-106.4814,-106.4782,-106.6504
I removed the " then use INSERT:
const data = msg.toString().replaceAll("\"", "")
            const tableName = datalogger.datalogger_name + '___' + device.Serial
            const query = `
                INSERT INTO ${tableName}(value)
                VALUES('${data}')
            `
            if(pgClient._connected ){
                pgClient.query(query)
                .then(() => { console.log('added data to ' + tableName) })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('added data to ' + tableName + ' failed: ', error, query)
                })
            }

But I got error:

error: invalid message format
    at C:\Users\vedax\Desktop\robot\cr1000\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:535:17
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
  length: 81,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '08P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'pqformat.c',
  line: '640',
  routine: 'pq_getmsgend'
}
                INSERT INTO CR1000X_1___2748(value)
                VALUES('2024-12-20 13:37:23.450,4783.923,5375.324,6897.892,4267.62,4205.655,12072.45,5280.143,7321.269,20.99808,20.53375,-112.3837,-112.5886,-106.6176,-106.4814,-106.4782,-106.6504        
')

Can someone point me what am I wrong? Thanks
Tried to search but nothing work to me

Does that sql statement work directly on the db? And VALUES('202... this structure will only insert one row, is that what you're expecting?

please [edit] the question to indicate which client library that is, as that's the source of the error. A possible lead/reference: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2900

It seems there are special characters at the end of the input, at least a new line. While it shouldn't, in itself, be an issue, it might be worth checking it.

Definitely would check @JGH 's suggestion, given the discussion at https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1115
